# Calculating remainder in batch?

Tags: batch-file

When entered manually into the commnand prompt, the following sequence works as desired:

```
>set /a r=3%2
1
>echo %r%
1
```

However, when launched from batchh file, it doesn't, as %2 clearly has a different meaning.

```
>set /a r=3%2

>echo %r%
3
```

How do I make the batch file do what I did in the first example, claculating the remainder?
The system in question is XP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this syntax in batch-files:

```
set /a "r=3 %% 2"
```

Comment: It's better to read if you use `3 %% 2` and will not confuse anyone in future with a %2 in there.